# Collection View Cells are keep increasing as twice of the current array count

Tags: ios, json, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Hi I am using data model method to load data into `collectionView` cells. Data fetching successful but when I navigate to another `viewController` and coming back to the current `viewController` the cells are increasing as twice as the current array count.

I know the method I used is not perfect one because I am new to Swift and I got those from google. What is the proper way to handle this?

API CALL

```
func postToGetMyCoach()
    {
        let url = "https://xxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/myCoach"
        var param : [String : AnyObject] = [:]

        param = ["apiKey": apiKey as AnyObject]
        print(param)
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding()).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

            if (response.result.value != nil)
            {
               if let value = response.result.value
               {
                let json = JSON(value)
                //  let responseDictionary = json.dictionaryValue as [String: AnyObject]
              //  print("json:\(json)")

                /**** Category Array exctraction *****/
                let categoryArray = json["data"]["categories"].arrayValue
                print("Category Array:\(categoryArray)")

                for var mCategory in categoryArray
                {
                    let title = mCategory["title"].stringValue
                    let imageURL = mCategory["image"].stringValue
                    let id = mCategory["id"].stringValue

                    //Escape image url additional Charectors
                    self.cimageURL = imageURL.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
                    print("ESCAPED IMAGE URL\(self.cimageURL)")

                //    let mcCategory = categories(description: description, title: title, id :id, dateOfNews: dateOfNews, imageURL:self.cimageURL)
                    let mcCategory = MCCategories(title: title, id:id, imageURL:self.cimageURL)

                    self.categories.append(mcCategory)

                }
                self.collectionView.reloadData()

               }
            }
            else
            {
                print("No Response!",response)
            }
        }
```

Collectionview Delegates

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCoachCCell", for: indexPath)
            as! MyCoachCCell

       // cell.activitiesImg.image = collectionViewImageArray[indexPath.row]
        let mCategories = categories[indexPath.row]
        cell.className.text = mCategories.title
     //   cell.classThumb.image = collectionViewImageArray[indexPath.row]

        // fetching image
        let mcImageURL = mCategories.imageURL
        Alamofire.request(mcImageURL).responseData(completionHandler: { response in
            //   debugPrint(response)
            //   debugPrint(response.result)
            if let image1 = response.result.value {
                self.imagefinal = UIImage(data: image1)!
                cell.classThumb.image = self.imagefinal
                print("IMG", self.imagefinal! )

            }
        })

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Where do you call the postToGetMyCoach method from?

Comment: please write this line of code before append in array "self.categories.removeAll()"

Comment: @LloydKeijzer  in viewWillAppear

Comment: You are calling API function again, so again api data apending to already existed Category array. Use below function, I have posted

Comment: You should only fetch your data array with postToGetMyCoach() once from the viewDidLoad method and fetch and append new items inside the viewWillAppear. Or as mentioned above clear the array and fetch it again. But that doesnt seem to be very efficient to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please write the code before appending into array.

```
self.categories.removeAll()
```

In your function add this line before starting of for loop.

```
func postToGetMyCoach()
    {
        let url = "https://xxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/myCoach"
        var param : [String : AnyObject] = [:]

        param = ["apiKey": apiKey as AnyObject]
        print(param)
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding()).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

            if (response.result.value != nil)
            {
               if let value = response.result.value
               {
                let json = JSON(value)
                //  let responseDictionary = json.dictionaryValue as [String: AnyObject]
              //  print("json:\(json)")

                /**** Category Array exctraction *****/
                let categoryArray = json["data"]["categories"].arrayValue
                print("Category Array:\(categoryArray)")

                self.categories.removeAll()
                for var mCategory in categoryArray
                {
                    let title = mCategory["title"].stringValue
                    let imageURL = mCategory["image"].stringValue
                    let id = mCategory["id"].stringValue

                    //Escape image url additional Charectors
                    self.cimageURL = imageURL.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
                    print("ESCAPED IMAGE URL\(self.cimageURL)")

                //    let mcCategory = categories(description: description, title: title, id :id, dateOfNews: dateOfNews, imageURL:self.cimageURL)
                    let mcCategory = MCCategories(title: title, id:id, imageURL:self.cimageURL)

                    self.categories.append(mcCategory)

                }
                self.collectionView.reloadData()

               }
            }
            else
            {
                print("No Response!",response)
            }
        }
```

you have call the webservice in viewWillAppear method.So, whenever you come back from another view controller it will append the data in same existing array.So, writing above code will remove the existing data from array.

or other you can do is call the webservice in **viewDidLoad** method.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: when I remove all repeating problem solves but my array count was 2 but now it's loading only 1. wait I will call the api on viewdidload and check.

Comment: Okay check and let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: Remove all is not solving the issue fully but when I call the api in viewdidload solved me without remove all line. Thanks.

Comment: please edit ur answer and keep only viewdidload part

Comment: It's working but I don't know why some of cells are missing from existing response

Comment: please replace your function with this one and check. I think this should be work proper.

Comment: oops I called self.categories.removeAll() inside the loop that caused. anyway this is perfect solution Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your function with this one.

You need to remove all elements from array categories before appending.

```
func postToGetMyCoach()
{
    let url = "https://xxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/myCoach"
    var param : [String : AnyObject] = [:]

    param = ["apiKey": apiKey as AnyObject]
    print(param)
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding()).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        if (response.result.value != nil)
        {
           if let value = response.result.value
           {
            let json = JSON(value)
            //  let responseDictionary = json.dictionaryValue as [String: AnyObject]
          //  print("json:\(json)")

            /**** Category Array exctraction *****/
            let categoryArray = json["data"]["categories"].arrayValue
            print("Category Array:\(categoryArray)")

            self.categories = []
            for var mCategory in categoryArray
            {
                let title = mCategory["title"].stringValue
                let imageURL = mCategory["image"].stringValue
                let id = mCategory["id"].stringValue

                //Escape image url additional Charectors
                self.cimageURL = imageURL.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
                print("ESCAPED IMAGE URL\(self.cimageURL)")

            //    let mcCategory = categories(description: description, title: title, id :id, dateOfNews: dateOfNews, imageURL:self.cimageURL)
                let mcCategory = MCCategories(title: title, id:id, imageURL:self.cimageURL)

                self.categories.append(mcCategory)

            }
            self.collectionView.reloadData()

           }
        }
        else
        {
            print("No Response!",response)
        }
    }
```